# Delicious PHP oAuth Yahoo SDK Add Bookmark

Tags: oauth, yahoo, delicious-api

I'm really having a difficult time trying to find a way to successfully authenticate a user and post a bookmark to their delicious account.

I downloaded [Yahoo's YOS Social SDK](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php) then began modifying the oauth [sampleapp.php](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php/blob/master/sample/sampleapp.php). It basically handles the oAuth process by creating a login link that sends you to Yahoo to grant permission then sends you back to the callback URL you specify.

My thought was to modify the sampleapp.php file to make a request to delicious [posts/add API](http://www.delicious.com/help/api#posts_add) to add a new bookmark once they oAuth process is over, but I'm running into some problems. I think I'm handling the POST request in the wrong manner.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__).'/lib/Yahoo.inc';

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
YahooLogger::setDebug(true);
YahooLogger::setDebugDestination('LOG');

ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
session_save_path('/tmp/');
session_start();

define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY', '<YOURS_GOES_HERE>');
define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET', '<YOURS_GOES_HERE>');
define('OAUTH_DOMAIN', '<YOURS_GOES_HERE>');
define('OAUTH_APP_ID', '<YOURS_GOES_HERE>');

if(array_key_exists("logout", $_GET)) {
  YahooSession::clearSession();
  header("Location: sampleapp.php");
}

$hasSession = YahooSession::hasSession(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_APP_ID);

if($hasSession == FALSE) {

  $callback = YahooUtil::current_url();
  $auth_url = YahooSession::createAuthorizationUrl(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, $callback);

}
else {

  $session = YahooSession::requireSession(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_APP_ID);

  if($session) {

    $consumer = new stdclass();
        $consumer->key = OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY;
        $consumer->secret = OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET;

    $nativeSession = new NativeSessionStore();
    $token = $nativeSession->fetchAccessToken();

    $client = new OAuthClient($consumer, $token, OAUTH_PARAMS_IN_HEADERS, OAUTH_SIGNATURE_HMAC_SHA1);

    $request_url = 'http://api.del.icio.us/v2/posts/add';
    $bookmark_url = 'http://www.tegdesign.com';
    $parameters = array("url" => urlencode($bookmark_url), "description" => "test");

    $response = $client->post($request_url,'TEXT',$parameters);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($response);
    echo '</pre>';

  }

}


if($hasSession == FALSE) {

  echo sprintf("<a href=\"%s\" id=\"yloginLink\">Login</a>\n", $auth_url);

} else if($hasSession) {

  echo "<p><a href=\"?logout\">Logout</a></p>";

}

?>
```

And here is the output of $response variable:

```
Array
(
    [method] => POST
    [url] => http://api.del.icio.us/v2/posts/add
    [code] => 401
    [requestHeaders] => Array
        (
            [0] => Accept: application/json
            [1] => Authorization: OAuth realm="yahooapis.com",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_nonce="<MINE_SHOWS_HERE>",oauth_timestamp="1289407587",oauth_consumer_key="<MINE_SHOWS_HERE>",oauth_token="<MINE_SHOWS_HERE>",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="<MINE_SHOWS_HERE>"
            [2] => Content-Type: TEXT
        )

    [requestBody] => Array
        (
            [url] => http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tegdesign.com
            [description] => test
        )

    [responseHeaders] => Array
        (
            [Date] => Wed, 10 Nov 2010 16:46:32 GMT
            [WWW-Authenticate] => OAuth oauth_problem="signature_invalid", realm="yahooapis.com"
            [Content-Type] => application/json
            [Cache-Control] => private
            [Age] => 0
            [Transfer-Encoding] => chunked
            [Connection] => keep-alive
            [Server] => YTS/1.17.21
        )

    [responseBody] => {"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"Please provide valid credentials"}}
)
```

Does anybody have knowledge on using Delicious new API to successfully authenticate and post a bookmark on behalf a user? I'm having a terrible time.

Thanks,
Tegan

Answer (score 1):

Set your content type to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` instead of `'Text'` on the below line.

```
$response = $client->post($request_url,'TEXT',$parameters);
```